# "Unable to reduce RAID LV - operation not implemented"

Tags: 14.04, raid, lvm

I've created a logical volume using Ubuntu 14.04 that started off at 80GiB. I resized it to 128GiB, but now I'd like to reduce back to 80GiB. There's an ext4 file system filling the volume. My command syntax is as follows:

```
sudo lvreduce -r -L 80g /dev/[volgroup]/[volname]
```

The file system always shrinks successfully (I know this from attempting it as separate resize2fs and lvresize operations), but lvresize consistently returns the following error:

```
Unable to reduce RAID LV - operation not implemented.
```

I created a test LV and filled it with an ext4 file system. I'm able to extend and reduce it at will with the same command, so why can't I reduce this other volume?

Other thoughts: I've also tried reducing the filesystem first with an extra buffer of space, say to 70GiB, and then reducing the volume to 80GiB, but with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. For some reason, I'm not able to reduce a logical volume while it's in a mirror. For each volume I'm looking to reduce, I'll have to split the mirror, reduce the size as desired, delete the copy created by the split, and re-convert the original volume to a mirror. Seems like more steps than are necessary, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

try:

1. resize2fs /dev/[volgroup]/[volname] 70G
2. lvreduce -L 80G /dev/[volgroup]/[volname]
3. resize2fs /dev/[volgroup]/[volname]

If second step fail - show details of volume group/lvm - maybe there it any strange configuration (raid on lvm?)